# Calculating function on files from directory

Tags: c

I wrote a code that calculate something. As I have many files, I am trying to rewrite the code, that it can read a files from a folder, calculate some function and give an output in another folder. I found some examples how I can make it, but something is wrong. As an output I did not received every file (ex. I have 5 input files in a folder, but I received only 4 files with results). What I am doing wrong? Here is my main part of the code:

```
int main()
{
int my_size = 100;
char katalogIn[512];
strcpy(katalogIn, "input");
char katalogOut[512];
strcpy(katalogOut, "output");

DIR *dp;
struct dirent *entry;
struct stat statbuf;
if ((dp = opendir(katalogIn)) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open directory: %s\n", katalogIn);
    return 1;
}

int fileCounter = 0;
char fileName[512];

    while ((entry = readdir(dp)) != NULL) {
       lstat(entry->d_name, &statbuf);
       fileCounter++;
       if (S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode)) {
    //printf("Done");
       } else {

     if (fileName != NULL)
     {
        FILE *fileData1;
            strcpy(fileName, katalogIn);
            strcat(fileName, "/");
            strcat(fileName, entry->d_name);
            fileData1 = fopen(fileName, "r");
            if (fileData1 == NULL) {
                printf("Cannot open the file\n");
                return -1;
            }

            char buffor[512];
    float *x = (float*)malloc(my_size * sizeof(float));
    float *y = (float*)malloc(my_size * sizeof(float));
    float *z = (float*)malloc(my_size * sizeof(float));
    if (x != NULL && y != NULL && z != NULL)
    {
        int i;
        fseek(fileData1, 0, 0);
        for (i = 0; i < my_size; i++)
        {
            if (fscanf(fileData1, "%f\t%f\t%f", x + i, y + i, z +i) != 3)

            {
                break;
            }
        }
        fclose(fileData1);

        FILE *fileOutput1;
            strcpy(fileName, katalogOut);
            strcat(fileName, "/");
            strcat(fileName, entry->d_name);
            //strcat(fileName,"out");
            fileOutput1 = fopen(fileName, "w");
            if (fileOutput1 == NULL) {
                printf("Cannot open the file\n");
                return -1;
            }

        for (i = 0; i < my_size; i++)
        {
            float convX, convY;
            int successCode = my_func(x[i], y[i], &convX, &convY);
            fprintf(fileOutput1,"%.2f\t%.2f\t%.2f\n", convX, convY,z[i]);

        }
        free(x);
        free(y);
        free(z);
        fclose(fileOutput1);
    }
      }

   }}

closedir(dp);
return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `readdir` loop, the name of the "entry" (`entry->d_name`) is the *relative* name to the directory it's in. So if you have a file `/input/foo` then `entry->d_name` will be `"foo"` only.

You should really check what [`lstat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lstat.2.html) *returns*. I'll bet it's `-1` with [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) set to `ENOENT` (which means `statbuf` is uninitialized and all members will have *indeterminate* values).

To get `lstat` to not fail, you either need to [`chdir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) into the directory, or you should have a temporary string where you concatenate the directory and file names. Something you do later in the code (though I would suggest using `snprintf` instead of three string function calls).

---

There are also a few other problems that looks weird. For example `fileName` is an array, which means it will *never* be `NULL`.

Also please read [this discussion about casting the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Not that you need to allocate dynamically, since you have a size fixed at time of compilation which means you could use arrays for `x`, `y` and `z`.

Comment: I think that I do not understand how I can correct my code. After adding a line chdir(katalogIn); there is an error "Cannot open the file". And about weird things in my code: I'm learning C by myself, so I know that many things can be done in a better way, but on one file it was working correctly.

Comment: @raquela That's because you *later* in the code use the whole "appending directory and file name" thing. Since you do that, *don't* do the `chdir` and instead move the "appending directory and file name" thing to before the call to `lstat`. Like `snprintf(fileName, sizeof(fileName), "%s/%s", katalogIn, entry->d_name); int res = lstat(fileName); ...`.